# Django, recuperar valor selecionado na página

Tags: html5, python, django

Boa noite!

Eu criei uma view onde recupero os vendedores e criei uma variável (id_vendedor) para receber o vendedor selecionado na tela. O html está sendo criado corretamente, mas a variável na view não recebe valor no POST:

View:

```
 def novo_orcamento(request):
    vendedores = Vendedor.objects.order_by('nome')
    id_vendedor = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()


    context = {'vendedores':vendedores, 'id_vendedor':id_vendedor}

    return render(request, 'appOrcamento/novo_orcamento.html', context)
```

Html

```
{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'appOrcamento:novo_orcamento' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <legend class="lead">PRODUTOS</legend>
        <select name=id_vendedor class="form-control">
            {% for vendedor in vendedores %}
                <option value="{{vendedor.codigo_id}}">{{vendedor.nome}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>

        <button name='submit' class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Como devo fazer para recuperar o vendedor selecionado na view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No html altera o name do select para usar aspas:

```
<select name="id_vendedor">
```

E na tua view pega os dados através do objeto request.

```
def novo_orcamento(request):
    id_vendedor = request.POST.get("id_vendedor")
    #Faz os processamentos com esse valor
```

Comment: Marlysson, obrigado pela sua ajuda.  Funcionou perfeitamente, vou encerrar a minha dúvida com a sua reposta.